# How to merge result of two or more queries of firebase firestore v9 in reactJs?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have these 3 queries but I want to merge the result of these queries, is there any way to do this.
I am using firebase version 9 in react 18.
The database I am using is firebase firestore.

```
const q1 = query(
  collection(db, "users"),
  where("username", "==", search)
);

const q2 = query(
  collection(db, "users"),
  where("CurrentCity", "==", search)
);

const q3 = query(
  collection(db, "users"),
  where("HomeTown", "==", search)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `query()` function just creates a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.query) but doesn't fetch the data. To run the query, you need to use `getDocs()` function. Then if you are trying to get documents from all queries in a single array, try:

```
const snapshots = await Promise.all([
  getDocs(q1),
  getDocs(q2),
  getDocs(q3), 
]);

const result = snapshots.map(qSnap => {
  return qSnap.docs.map((d) => ({
    id: d.id,
    ...d.data()
  }))
})
```