# React Native Firebase - query with logical AND

Tags: firebase, react-native-firebase

I have a backlog of tasks. Every task has `createAt` and `isDone` fields.
I would like to query all tasks which are not done except for the current date. For the current date, I would like to get every task independent of status.

```
where( isDone == false if date < currentDate)
```

is there any way in Firebase to get this or I have to query 2 times and merge results?

Comment: What is the exact database you're using? Firestore or the Realtime Database?

Comment: It might be easier to run 2 queries - one to fetch all documents of with date currentDate and another to query tasks with isDone true but date is not currentDate. In case you are using Firestore, is this what you are looking for? [How to merge result of 2 queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74573754/13130697)

Comment: Yes, I've done 2 queries, but it's so weird. so many limitations - have feeling that I'm doing something wrong :)

Because I also want to merge results by "createdAt" field. So, I have to merge results and sort after merge. 

Also, `not-in` condition is not available for empty array.